# How to make a prediction with model that returns MultiArray(Double) in Swift

Tags: swift, coreml

I trained a model with Keras and converted it to CoreML using CoreMLTools. You can see details about the model here:

[image]

How can I make predictions with this model? When i try I get this error:

```
2019-12-30 13:07:01.564792-0800 agricultural-helper[16042:6014777] [espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Espresso exception: "Invalid argument": generic_reshape_kernel: Invalid bottom shape (512 28 -3 1 1) for reshape to (512 -1 1 1 1) status=-6
2019-12-30 13:07:01.565447-0800 agricultural-helper[16042:6014777] [coreml] Error computing NN outputs -6
Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error computing NN outputs." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error computing NN outputs.}
```

Here is my code:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    let options = MLPredictionOptions()
    options.usesCPUOnly = true
    let model = CropDisease()
    let uiImage = UIImage(named: "test.png")!
    let pixelBuffer = buffer(from: uiImage)!
    let modelInput = CropDiseaseInput(conv2d_input: pixelBuffer)

    do {
        let output = try model.prediction(input: modelInput, options: options)
        print(output)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func buffer(from image: UIImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
  var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
  let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
  guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
    return nil
  }

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
  let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

  let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
  let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

  context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
  context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

  UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
  image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
  UIGraphicsPopContext()
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

  return pixelBuffer
}
```

Anything helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Core ML model has an internal problem. Try making a prediction from Python using coremltools. My guess is you'll get the same error message.

If this is really the case, then the solution is to figure out where exactly in the model the problem occurs. The error message already gives a pretty big hint:

```
generic_reshape_kernel: Invalid bottom shape (512 28 -3 1 1) 
for reshape to (512 -1 1 1 1)
```

There is a layer somewhere that is getting a tensor of shape (512, 28, -3, 1, 1) but is expecting (512, -1, 1, 1, 1). Note that the -1 isn't necessarily an issue (usually this means "automatically calculate the size for this dimension") but the -3 looks problematic...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Giving it a try right now!

Comment: Unfortunately, haven't been able to find too much. Could it be a problem with grayscale vs color images?

Comment: If you're passing in a wrong image (not enough pixels etc) then Core ML will give a different error, so I doubt it is that. What framework did you use to train this model, TF 2.0 perhaps?

Comment: I see. Yes I used TF2.0

Comment: Support for TF 2.0 was only very recently added to coremltools, so no doubt it will still have bugs. You might be running into one of those here. Hard to say without seeing the actual mlmodel file.

Comment: having the same problem, did you solve it?